# How Can I Change the Default Database from DynamoDB to PostgreSQL Aurora in an AWS Amplify Project?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify, amazon-aurora

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I am creating a project using AWS Amplify, but I want to use PostgreSQL Aurora instead of the default database DynamoDB in this project. However, I couldn't find any option in Amplify Studio to change the database.

Is there anyone who can help with this? How can I switch the database from DynamoDB to PostgreSQL Aurora?

Thank you.

I've tried experimenting with Amplify Studio and AWS AppSync, but unfortunately, I couldn't achieve the desired results. Are there any further instructions or suggestions on how to switch the database from DynamoDB to PostgreSQL Aurora? I appreciate your assistance.

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/connect-amplify-datastore-with-existing-sql-datasources-adding-offline-and-sync-features-in-your-application/